# Message to all the contacts that are using whatsapp using a service in my contact list

Tags: android

**What I am trying to do:**

- I am trying to send message to all the contacts that are using
  whatsapp using a service in my contact list
- Is it possible ?
- If possible how ?

**What I am able to do:** I am able to launch whats app withh intent and I can pass a text message to it, then send message through a single contact or a group created by me

---

**DownloadService.java**

```
public class DownloadService extends Service {

    public static boolean serviceState = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        serviceState = true;
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("SERVICE-ONCOMMAND", "onStartCommand");

        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.d("SERVICE-DESTROY", "DESTORY");
        serviceState = false;
        //Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // We don't provide binding, so return null
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.samples.customprogressloader" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".DownloadService"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

In `OnCreate` method of activity I am starting the service as,

```
startService(new Intent(this, DownloadService.class));
```

---

[***I am using this method to send message through whats app from here docs***](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012)

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `READ_CONTACTS` permission in manifest. You can get contact which uses `com.whatsapp`.

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
        RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] { RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY },
        RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?",
        new String[] { "com.whatsapp" },
        null);

int contactIDColumn = c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.CONTACT_ID );
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault(); // **SEND_SMS** permission needed
while (c.moveToNext())
{
  String whatsAppContact =   c.getString(contactIDColumn);
  smsManager.sendTextMessage(whatsAppContact, null, message, null, null);
}
```

Comment: About that SMS logic, If you have 10 entries as a result of the answer ... I have to launch what's app 10 times .... is there a way I can send message to all 10-entries through whatsapp  ?

Comment: You want to sent SMS or Whatsapp text?

Comment: You can not send bulk messages programatically in Whatsapp.

Comment: Thanks [+1] .... i am clear we cannot send bulk messages through whats app .... but how is it done through sms, any existing Stackoverflow answers for that

Comment: You can send Text SMS if you want I can edit my answer

Comment: Please do the Edit on How to send bulk messages :)

Comment: @Devrath if its useful to you then its should an accepted answer. :)